# Non-trivial blocks of order $16$ of $D_{16}$ acting on $8$-gon vertices

Tags: group-theory, permutations, group-actions, symmetric-groups, dihedral-groups

I would like to know exactly how many non-trivial blocks has $D_{16}$ of order $16$ acting on $8$ vertices of $8$-gon. I guess I should do it taking blocks as unions of the orbit of stabilisers but I don't know exactly how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** The action of $D_{16}$ on the set $X$ of vertices is clearly transitive, so the blocks containing a **fixed** vertice $x\in X$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the subgroups of $D_{16}$ containing the stabilizer $G_x$ of $x$.

Now , what are the rotations fixing $x$ ? what are the symmetries fixing $x$?